# AVL Tree Double Rotation error

Tags: c++, nodes, avl-tree

I am working on a project for school that involves implementing an AVL Tree using an iterative insert function and i am having an issue.

I am not 100% sure what i am not doing but my program is not giving the correct output.

Here is what i have for my insert function:

```
bool AVLTree::insert(string ss, string na){

AVLNode* newNode = new AVLNode(ss, na);
updateHeight(newNode);

//Tree is empty, make the new Node the root of a new tree
if(getRoot() == nullptr){
    root = newNode;
    print();
    return true;
}
//Tree is not empty
else{
    AVLNode* checkPoint;
    checkPoint = root;

    while(checkPoint != nullptr){

        //If the ssn is already in the tree
        if(checkPoint->ssn.compare(newNode->ssn) == 0){
            return false;
        }
        else if(checkPoint->ssn.compare(newNode->ssn) > 0){
            if(checkPoint->left == nullptr){
                break;
            }
            checkPoint = checkPoint->left;
        }
        else{
            if(checkPoint->right == nullptr){
                break;
            }
            checkPoint = checkPoint->right;
        }
    }

    if(newNode->ssn.compare(checkPoint->ssn) < 0){
        checkPoint->left = newNode;
    }
    else{
        checkPoint->right = newNode;
    }
    updateHeight(checkPoint);
    balance(root);
    print();
    return true;
}
```

This is my function that i have come up with so far, for my project i was provided with the balance function, and updateHeight which i will provide here:

```
AVLNode* AVLTree::balance(AVLNode* node){
updateHeight(node);
if (balanceFactor(node) == 2) {
    if (balanceFactor(node->left) < 0) {
        node->left = rotateLeft(node->left); // for left right case
    }

    AVLNode* temp = rotateRight(node);
    updateHeight(temp);
    return temp;
}

if (balanceFactor(node) == -2) {
    if (balanceFactor(node->right) > 0) {
        node->right = rotateRight(node->right);  // for right left case
    }
    AVLNode* temp2 = rotateLeft(node);
    updateHeight(temp2);
    return temp2;
}
return node;
```

And for the update height:

```
void AVLTree::updateHeight(AVLNode* node){
    int hl = height(node->left);
    int hr = height(node->right);
    node->height = (hl>hr ? hl : hr) + 1;
}
```

Basically my task was to implement the insert and delete functions. My input for the avl tree is in this order:

5, 8, 9, 3, 6, 7, 5

and my output is this:

```
      8
     / \
    5   9
   / \
  3   6
 /     \
2       7
```

when it should be:

```
        6
     /     \
    3       8
   / \     / \
  2   5   7   9
```

Going back to my insert function, what i believe is the problem is that i am not correctly updating the heights every time i insert a node. The program handles single rotations just fine but double rotations is what is not working. Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check and balance **all** the tree levels above the point of a node insertion.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, but how should i go about doing this, should i start at the newNode and go up or try to go down from the root and balance the entire tree?

Comment: I usually implement `insert` as a recursive function and when it exists a node it re-balances the entire sub-tree below the current node.

Comment: yeah everywhere i see online its all a recursive implementation. unfortunately, my professor has given us the requirement of doing this in a non-recursive way. So far my attempts to do this since you said that have been unsuccessful. However at least i have an idea on what i need to do next, thanks.

Comment: You can implement recursion manually. Store the nodes that the algorithm passes in a stack (can be implemented using an array) and iterate over the stack on the return from the function. There will be two loops: one for insert (can be nicknamed `i++`) and another for balance (nickname `--i`)

Comment: no wait dude, i got it, im dumb, i forgot to connect the newNode to the checkPoint going back up, meaning i had to add:                                        newNode->parent = checkPoint